# Exoplayer live seekbar and timeshift

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I use Exoplayer 2.8 to show HLS videos in my app.

For fix time contents seekbar works perfectly, but its useless for live content.

I want to show seekbar for past 12 hours and use it for timeshift, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Update: seems like there is already existing solutions:

1. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/87
2. https://github.com/jglanfield/ExoPlayer/tree/jdg-hls-rewind

You should take a look at [TimeLine](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Timeline.html) object and use it depending on you seekbar update logic.

Simple approach would be to store start time on your own in the code and then update it as frequent as you want with increasing playback and buffer.

More helpful answer would be if you would post some code that you already have, so anyone can guide you towards solution that will work for you.